# If $R$ is an anti-symmetric relation on A, then $R \circ R$ is an anti-symmetric relation on A.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> If $R$ is an anti-symmetric relation on A, then $R \circ R$ is an anti-symmetric relation on A.

I have to prove this to be true or false and am just not sure how to go about it. Any feedback is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Edit: This is the definition of antisymmetric we were given:
$R$ is antisymmetric if $(a, b) \in R$ and $a\neq b$ implies $(b, a) \not\in R$

Comment: In future, please use MathJax for maths notation and make sure the content of the question is standalone without reading the title.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: consider the relation on $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ given by the pairs $(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1).$

Comment: You can also simplify this hint to 2 elements :).

Comment: @Alan Could you give details on the claim of your comment?